# skopeo copy on remote registries hangs on RHEL8 NFS share

Tags: docker, docker-registry, podman, skopeo

skopeo copy hangs on NFS share.

skopeo inspect, list-tags work fine.

Relevant logs after which it is stuck forever

```
DEBU[0000] Manifest has MIME type application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, ordered candidate list [application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws, application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json] 

DEBU[0000] ... will first try using the original manifest unmodified
```

OS: RHEL8

Space and network are not an issue.

skopeo copy docker:// docker://

Should successfully work.

Comment: I tried updating the $HOME variable to point to the local drive and it worked.

**skopeo** is trying to write $HOME/.local/share/containers/cache/blob-info-cache-v1.boltdb.

As my $HOME is on NFS it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution.

I created a symlink on the NFS, linked to the path on the local drive and it worked.

```
ln -s <path-from-local-drive> $HOME/.local/share/containers/cache/blob-info-cache-v1.boltdb
```

skopeo copy successfully worked after this.